# Bifurcation Points of the Rossler Attractor

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I'm currently studying the Rossler attractor, which is the following system:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d}t}&=-(y+z)\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}&=x+\alpha y \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}t}&=\beta + z(x-\gamma).
\end{align*}
This system has a Jacobian of
\begin{equation*}
J^*=\begin{pmatrix}
0  & -1 & -1 \\
1 & \alpha & 0 \\
z & 0 & x-\gamma
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

I have found the equilibrium points of the system, which are
\begin{align*}
 (x^*,y^*,z^*)&=\Bigg(\frac{\gamma + \sqrt{\gamma^2 -4\alpha \beta}}{2}, \frac{-\gamma - \sqrt{\gamma^2 -4\alpha \beta}}{2\alpha} , \frac{\gamma + \sqrt{\gamma^2 -4\alpha \beta}}{2\alpha}\Bigg) \text{, and }\\
 (x^*,y^*,z^*)&=\Bigg(\frac{\gamma - \sqrt{\gamma^2 -4\alpha \beta}}{2}, \frac{-\gamma + \sqrt{\gamma^2 -4\alpha \beta}}{2\alpha} , \frac{\gamma - \sqrt{\gamma^2 -4\alpha \beta}}{2\alpha}\Bigg).
 \end{align*}

I now need to analyse the stability of the system at these equilibrium points, but when I attempt to do so I get the characteristic equations that are tough to solve.

I also need to find the bifurcation points, and plot a bifurcation diagram.
I think that bifurcation will occur when $\gamma^2 =4\alpha \beta$, but I'm not sure that I can prove it. And I have no idea how to plot a bifurcation diagram.

Can anyone offer me some help on how to proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A case $\gamma^2 = 4\alpha \beta$ can be treated just by definition of bifurcation: you have different number of equilibria in the system in the neighbourhood of points where $\gamma^2 = 4\alpha \beta$. For stability part I also recommend using [Routh-Hurwitz criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_stability_criterion). A set of parameters where this criterion fails also consists of bifurcation points.